# How to create database on OritentDB using OrientDB-NET.binary driver for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, orientdb

I'm starting to learn OrientDB using OrientDB-NET.binary driver for C# and I have successfully configured and ran OrientDB as server.

Now I just tried to run a connection using OClient.CreateDatabasePool as described here https://github.com/yojimbo87/OrientDB-NET.binary/wiki

```
OClient.CreateDatabasePool(
"127.0.0.1",
2424,
"TestDatabaseName",
ODatabaseType.Graph,
"admin",
"admin",
10,
"myTestDatabaseAlias");
```

and Im getting this error:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Database 'TestManualy' is not configured on server (home=E:/orientdb-community-2.1.16/databases/)
```

Is it possible to create "TestDatabaseName" database using the .NET driver?

If not, how to create database on OritentDB?

I will apreciate some sample code.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created the following example using OrientDB 2.1.16 and the .NET driver. Main steps:

1. If `TestDatabaseName` database already exists, I drop it;
2. Creating a new `TestDatabaseName` database;
3. Connecting and populating it.

**C# CODE:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Orient.Client;

namespace OrientTestCreateDB

{
    class CreateDB

    {

    private static string _hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    private static int _port = 2424;
    private static string _rootUserName = "root";
    private static string _rootUserPassword = "root";

    private static OServer _server;

    private static string _DBname = "TestDatabaseName";
    private static string _username = "admin";
    private static string _password = "admin";

    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        _server = new OServer(_hostname, _port, _rootUserName, _rootUserPassword);

        //If the DB already exists I delete it
        if (_server.DatabaseExist(_DBname, OStorageType.PLocal))

        {

            _server.DropDatabase("TestDatabaseName", OStorageType.PLocal);

            Console.WriteLine("Database " + _DBname + " deleted");

        }

        //Creating the new DB
        _server.CreateDatabase(_DBname, ODatabaseType.Graph, OStorageType.PLocal);

        Console.WriteLine("Database " + _DBname + " created");

        //Connect to the DB and populate it
        OClient.CreateDatabasePool(
        "127.0.0.1",
        2424,
        _DBname,
        ODatabaseType.Graph,
        _username,
        _password,
        10,
        "myTestDatabaseAlias"
        );

        Console.WriteLine("Connected to the DB " + _DBname);

        using (ODatabase database = new ODatabase("myTestDatabaseAlias"))

            {

                database
                     .Create.Class("TestClass")
                     .Extends<OVertex>()
                     .Run();

                OVertex createdVertex = database
                     .Create.Vertex("TestClass")
                     .Set("name", "LucaS")
                     .Run();

                Console.WriteLine("Created vertex with @rid " + createdVertex.ORID);

           }

       }

    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**OrientDB Studio output:**

[image]

**Second connection:**

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: I cant run your code. Witch version is it? Im using orientdb-community-2.1.16 and OrientDB-NET.binary 0.2.1, .NET 4.5.2. This enum just doesnt exist OStorageType.PLocal, I changed to OStorageType.Local and i found the enum. _server.DatabaseExist(_DBname, OStorageType.PLocal) accept just one parameter. OVertex doesnt exsist.

Comment: Hi, these are my specs: ODB community 2.1.16, ODB-NET 0.2.1, Visual Studio 2015. The first time I didn't encounter this issue because I didn't use nuget but I only created a reference to `Orient.Client.dll`. Anyway, I tried by using nuget and I encountered your same issue. I solved it by removing the `Orient.Client.dll` Reference from my project and then I reimported it by using `Add References...`. Probably the first time the reference isn't correctly created, could you try this instructions ?

Comment: Yes, I used nuget. Now I tried compiling and referencing the dll and it worked. Thanks a lot.